# Solr search using contains, sound like

Tags: search, solr, soundex

Problem:
I have a movie information in solr. Two string fields define the movie title and director name. A copy field define another field which solr search for default.

I would like to have google like search with limited scope as follows. How to achieve it.

**1)How to search solr for contains**

E.g.
a) If the movie director name is "John Cream", searching for joh won't return anything. However, searchign for John return the correct result.

b) If there is a movie title called **aaabbb** and another one called **aaa**, searching for aaa returns only one result. I need to return the both results.

**2) How to account for misspelling**

E.g. 
If the movie director name is "John Cream", searching for Jon returns no results. Is there a good sounds like (soundex) implementation for solr. If so how to enable it?

*You can use solr query syntax*

Comment: That's already given in the questions. Two string fields, one copy field. The packages are what comes with latest solr installation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Searching for contains is obviously possible using wildcards (eg: `title:*aaa*` will match 'aaabbb' and also 'cccaaabbb'), but be careful about it, becouse it doesn't use indexes efficently. Do you really need this?

A soundex like search is possible applying `solr.PhoneticFilterFactory` filter to both your index and query. To achieve this define your fieldType like this in schema:

```
<fieldType name="text_soundex" class="solr.TextField">
...
<filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="Soundex" inject="true"/>
</fieldType>
```

If you define your "director" field as "text_soundex" you'll be able to search for "Jon" and find "John"

See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters for more information.

Comment: It does not match title:'aaabbb in my case. I don't know why. It matches if anything start before aaabbb, foe example daaabbb. I made custom fildType string_ci with this setup: <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>

Comment: It seems I have to use :LetterTokenizerFactory

Answer (score 2):

Things you are asking, the first one is definitely achievable from Solr. I don't know about soundex.

**1)How to search solr for contains**
You can store data into string type of field or text type of field. In string field by wild card searching you can achieve the result (E.g field1:"John*"). Also you should look into different types of [analyzers](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters). But before everything, please look into the Solr reference http://wiki.apache.org/solr/.

Answer (score 1):

```
def self.get_search_deals(search_q, per = 50)
  data =  Sunspot.search(Deal) do
    fulltext '*'+search_q +'*', fields: :title
    paginate page: page_no, per_page: per
  end
  data.results
end

searchable do
  text    :title
end

just pass string as "*sam*"
```